# Core Data Lightweight Migration with NSManagedObject Subclasses and Relationships

Tags: ios, core-data, model, migration, schema

I am updating my Core Data model to include more entities and attributes and need some guidance when it comes to relationships and NSManagedObjectSubclasses.

I have followed the guidance here http://www.raywenderlich.com/27657/how-to-perform-a-lightweight-core-data-migration and successfully managed to add a new model version of my app, add in a new entity with an attribute and set up the relationship to another entity. I have also managed to successfully update the AppDelegate settings.

That's working very well. However, I need to generate an NSManagedObject Subclass for my new entity as well as update the relationship with another entity with it's NSManagedObjectSubclass.

I have tested my app and it's still working with the data in tact, but if I generate a new NSmanagedObject subclass for the new entity and regenerate the NSManagedOBject subclass for the other entity that has a relationship to this new entity, won't that require me to delete the app from the phone with the model mismatch?

I have not tried it because I need to test this out before making changes, but I needed some guidance on this issue.

Comment: Are you saying that you made some changes to the model, tested it on the device, and that you want to make and test *additional* changes to the model? If so, are you using any type of source code control?

Comment: Thanks Trevor - sorry, I'll just provide some further information. I have created the new model with a new entity and relationship to the existing model, updated the AppDelegate code and tested on a device and it works. However, I need to generate a new NSManagedObject subclass from the new entity and also to regenerate the entity on the other end of the relationship to this new entity.. and I have not tested that part yet because I am concerned that this will affect the existing database? Or will it be okay? No documentation points to the use of NSManagedObject subclasses with Lightweight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Migrations only affect the persistent store, making sure that it matches your managed object model.

Your NSManagedObject subclasses *use* the model and persistent store, but they don't *influence* it.

So yes, you can safely continue with your next step: making sure that your NSManagedObject subclasses (and other parts of your application) are updated to handle the structure of your newly-updated managed object model.

But just to make it absolutely clear: if you change the model *again* (tweaking relations etc) then your test device's database may become incompatible and you may need to start over with your migration tests.

This is why I asked if you use source control. You will almost certainly want to build and install previous versions of your app so you can repeatedly test migrations.

Comment: Dear Trevor - my apologies for the late reply but that is honestly super helpful. With working with the NSManagedObject subclasses this morning, as you said, it did not affect the model and I could migrate from older versions. I use the git built into Xcode and I have multiple copies of older versions of my app, as well as 2 devices dedicated to older versions, so I'll be able to test the migration with those as well. Thanks so much - this really helps me progress!